Emulate multihost traffic on localhost
I have app A and app B that communicates over tcp. I have no control over A, but B is my app (C++ with asio). I want to test the communication between them on localhost, however app A seem to handle traffic coming from localhost differently. I want to make it such that when A get a request from B it should think it's not from localhost so it does not apply its special localhost logic.
Here is what I have tried:

I have tried adding another ip like so: sudo ip addr add 192.168.1.10/32 dev lo and then in my app use bind on the socket to this ip. Based on logging from app B it seem that I then request from 192.168.1.10.
Similarly I have tried the same command but with my network interface eth0 instead of lo.

However both app A and wireshark still see the request originating from 127.0.0.1.
What else can I try?

Run your app in a container and then interact with it using the container ip address.

or kvm or similar guest (i.e. using vagrant)

I had hoped to not have to use containers unless that is the only way.

I love network namespaces and veths for things like this, similar isolation to containers (docker and other containerization engines use namespaces) but a bit more lightweight and easier to get going ad-hoc.
You can create a namespace with ip netns as in ip netns add memorable_name, create as many as you like, but one will get the job done.
You can then link your namespaces together with veth interfaces. ip link add type veth creates a pair of virtual ethernet interfaces that are linked together, and one can be moved to your namespace with ip link set veth1 netns memorable_name.
You can configure the interfaces in the usual way, with the exception that you need to use -n memorable_name if your shell is running in a different namespace than the interface you want to configure. ip a a 192.168.0.1/24 dev veth0 and ip -n memorable_name a a 192.168.0.2/24. Bring the interfaces up with ip link set veth0 up and ip -n memorable_name link set veth1 up and you're away.
To run a program in the new interface you can use ip netns exec as in ip netns exec memorable_name ./my_app or ip netns exec memorable_name bash.
